# How to cast string to timestamp in pyspark with month in format MMM

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

How do I cast to timestamp when I have the month in the format NOV?

I tried the below but I get this error:

`

```
master_ = master.withColumn("datetime_london", 
        F.to_timestamp("date_time", "dd-MMM-yy'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

`

> SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '14-NOV-2022T05:30:00' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
> Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text '14-NOV-2022T05:30:00' could not be parsed at index 9

If I remove the T in my timestamp it returns another error. I also tried "d-M-y'T'HH:mm:ss" but this returns a null.

Comment: Always add your sample input and expected output

Comment: Try `dd-MMM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss`. You have 4 digit year in your error msg.